# Curl connection error

Tags: curl

The curl Command is working on one server and does not work on other.

```
> $ curl http://yahoo.com
> <HEAD><TITLE>Redirect</TITLE></HEAD>
> <BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black">
> <FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial"><B>  The
> document you requested is now <a
> href="http://www.yahoo.com/">http://www.yahoo.com/</a>.
> Please update your documents and
> bookmarks accordingly</B></FONT>
> 
> <!-- default "Redirect" response (301)
> --> </BODY>
```

And on the other server, I get the following message.

```
$ curl http://yahoo.com
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

What is wrong with the second server?

Ping is working on the second server.

```
$ ping yahoo.com
PING yahoo.com (67.195.160.76) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ir1.fp.vip.ac4.yahoo.com (67.195.160.76): icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=79.9 ms
64 bytes from ir1.fp.vip.ac4.yahoo.com (67.195.160.76): icmp_seq=2 ttl=50 time=80.5 ms
```

Telneting returns an error

```
$ telnet yahoo.com 80
Trying 222.333.444.555...
telnet: connect to address 222.333.444.555: Connection refused
```

Comment: Can you telnet to port 80 from the second host?

Comment: Your 'telnet yahoo.com 80' output is clearly bogus - dotted decimal addresses have numbers up to 255.  So, what did you actually get?  Did you try connecting (on port 80) to the 67.195.160.76 address you got from pinging yahoo.com?  I won't be surprised to find it refusing the connection.  Can you connect to Yahoo from the second machine using a regular browser, or `lynx` even?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The network connection isn't working on the second host.  Maybe there's a firewall preventing it talking to the outside world, or it is misconfigured, or ...

Comment: How do I allow only one Address for e.g. yahoo.com without changing the current firewall setup?